# Chrome extension - keyboard shortcuts don't work when published to store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Keyboard shortcuts work perfectly when ext is loaded as unpackaged in dev mode.
But when published to chrome web store and downloaded - they just refuse to work.

`manifest.json`

```
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Alt+B"
      },
      "description": "Open BGA form page"
    },
    "autocomplete": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Alt+Z"
      },
      "description": "Autocomplete form with BGA data"
    }
  }
```

`background-scripts/autocomplete.js`

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  if (command === "autocomplete") {
    do_stuff()
  }
});
```

Comment: With issues like this, I'd start by trying a separate portable browser with a pristine new profile. Either there's something wrong with the main profile or it's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have helped:

- Remove both unpackaged extension and downloaded one
- Re-launch Chrome
- Re-install ext. from web Store
- voilá

Comment: Your problem was likely conflicting key bindings between the _two instances_ of the same enabled extension.